# What are the ways to say "endure austerity"?

Tags: translation

How can we say "endure austerity" in both formal and informal situations?

For example, how can we say:

- "The people of Greece are currently enduring austerities."
- "If you have to endure such austerities to afford a house, you are probably not ready to buy a house." (In this case the meaning of "austerity" is probably less extreme than in the above example.)
- "The Buddha discovered that enduring austerity is not the path to enlightenment."

Comment: "austerity" in the economic sense (what Greece is experiencing) is 緊縮財政【きんしゅくざいせい】 (character-by-character, something like "constricted finance"). This sense of "austerity" is fairly different from, say, the "rigorous discipline" sense used in your third example; it just so happens that we use the same word for both in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Buddha on) enduring austerity == "禁欲の修行" ?

As for: ​Money-related "belt-tightening"  expressions

- For nations or cities -- 緊縮財政 (きんしゅくざいせい) (which senshin mentioned) and 緊縮政策,  緊縮財政政策, 金融引き締め政策、体質改善策
- For companies -- 緊縮経営, 減量経営, 体質改善策
- For an individual, couple, family, or household --

  - 節約、倹約、耐乏生活
  - つましい暮らし、緊縮生活、節約ライフ、倹約ライフ
  - 窮乏生活、かつかつの生活(暮らし)、食うや食わずの生活(暮らし)
  - 禁欲生活、貧乏生活、極貧生活、シンプル・ライフ、ミニマムライフ

`"endure ..."  -----  に甘んじる,  を我慢する,  に堪える, ...`

> "Scrimp and save in order to buy a house"    -->
>
> 家を買うために生活費を切り詰める。 .... 切りつめた家計で生活する

I'm sure there are many other similar or related expressions.